# Issue while writing xtext grammar file

Tags: dsl, xtext

Following is part of my grammar

```
TestLabelBase returns ResultExpressionRhs : 'VL:' path=STRING ;
AlphabateModifier : (abc?='ABC' | def?='DEF' | ghi?='GHI') ;
```

When I write following rule `TestLabel` it works fine:

```
TestLabel returns ResultExpressionRhs: TestLabelBase (modifier=AlphabateModifier)?;
```

but when I use following rule for `TestLabel` it says

> An unassigned rule call is not allowed, when the 'current' was already created.

```
TestLabel returns ResultExpressionRhs: (modifier=AlphabateModifier)? TestLabelBase ;
```

Can you please explain the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a read of [Parsing Expressions with Xtext](http://blog.efftinge.de/2010/08/parsing-expressions-with-xtext.html), specifically about *Therein the first element is an unassigned rule call*.

You need to change your rule to:

```
TestLabel returns ResultExpressionRhs
  : (modifier=AlphabateModifier)? base=TestLabelBase 
  ;
```

Cheers, Steve